# Swift - FAILURE: responseValidationFailed in Alamofire (StatusCode 401)

Tags: ios, swift, http, alamofire, http-status-code-401

I am developing an iOS app with `Swift3` and using `Alamofire` as network library.But it gives `responseValidationFailed` error with `Status Code: 401` on `HTTP` request. `API` and other configurations are correct but it gives error. Here is my network call -

```
//Register user
    private func registerUser() -> Void {
        Alamofire.request(
            URL(string: "my_url")!,
            method: .post,
            parameters: ["email": email!, "gender": gender, "age":"20" ,"password": password!])
            .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
            .responseJSON { (response) -> Void in
                print(self.CLASS_NAME+" -- registerUser()  -- response -- "+response.debugDescription)
              }

        }
    }
```

Here is my `debugDescription` -

```
RegistrationViewController -- registerUser()  -- response -- [Request]: POST http://beta.thesmartclubapp.com:3000/api/register/other/
[Response]: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x60000022f100> { URL: http://beta.thesmartclubapp.com:3000/api/register/other/ } { Status Code: 401, Headers {
    Connection =     (
        "keep-alive"
    );
    "Content-Length" =     (
        118
    );
    "Content-Type" =     (
        "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    );
    Date =     (
        "Tue, 02 Jan 2018 08:22:25 GMT"
    );
    Etag =     (
        "W/\"76-3KZXMvbalkbJsfbjY65r3dx/Mak\""
    );
    "Strict-Transport-Security" =     (
        "max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains"
    );
    Vary =     (
        Origin
    );
    "X-Content-Type-Options" =     (
        nosniff
    );
    "X-DNS-Prefetch-Control" =     (
        off
    );
    "X-Download-Options" =     (
        noopen
    );
    "X-Frame-Options" =     (
        SAMEORIGIN
    );
    "X-XSS-Protection" =     (
        "1; mode=block"
    );
} }
[Data]: 118 bytes
[Result]: FAILURE: responseValidationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseValidationFailureReason.unacceptableStatusCode(401))
[Timeline]: Timeline: { "Request Start Time": 536574145.442, "Initial Response Time": 536574146.054, "Request Completed Time": 536574146.310, "Serialization Completed Time": 536574146.310, "Latency": 0.613 secs, "Request Duration": 0.868 secs, "Serialization Duration": 0.000 secs, "Total Duration": 0.868 secs }
```

**I searched on Google and Stackoverflow . Other solutions did not work for me.** 
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Http code 401 means Unauthorized. Looks you need to login first.

Comment: On where i need to login? but my android app is working fine.  @YunCHEN

Comment: Ahh... sorry, it's a register action! Do you config the option NSAppTransportSecurity in plist to allow access http url(not https)?

Comment: Yes, I have it on `info.plist` @YunCHEN

Comment: I'm seeing `[Data]: 118 bytes`, can you get that data? Maybe there is custom info there returned by response.

Comment: No i cant get the `data` @Larme

Comment: Could you print `print("responeData: \(response.data as NSData))` and also if possible `print("responeDataStr: \(String.init(data: response.data, encoding: .utf8)))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give a **name**(and confirm password also, check all the rules set by service), because service needs that. See the result gotten by postman.

[image]

The updated old answer : remove `.validate(statusCode: 200..<300)` is part of true reason,

Comment: Finally it worked. I had to remove `.validate(statusCode: 200..<300)` and also had to add `encoding: JSONEncoding.default` on the request.

Comment: Your API devs are so funny. Why do we need both bool flags `success` and `error` :D. And if you send the post params with the wrong format, it should be `Bad Request`, not `Unauthorized`.